# Scanner Reading Data file Java.Util.NoSuchElementException: Null

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I'm trying to write a class that will take in numbers from a file, but I keep running into this error when I run:
Java.util.NoSuchElementException: Null(in java.util.Scanner)
This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class finalMain
{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
{
  int lineNumber = 0;
   Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File ("Prog349f.txt"));

    System.out.println("Student  Quiz 1  Quiz2    MidTerm   Final      Final %     Grade");

    while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {

        lineNumber++;
        sc.nextLine();
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= 1; i++)
    {
       int quizOne = sc.nextInt();
       int quizTwo = sc.nextInt();
       int midterm = sc.nextInt();
       int finalTest = sc.nextInt();

       finalGrade studentNext = new finalGrade(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt(),sc.nextInt(), i);
       System.out.println(studentNext);
    }
    sc.close();
}
}
```

I'm thinking maybe I need to create two scanner objects, one for each line or something but I don't know how I would go about doing that.

Comment: Including the exception and its message is the thing to do, but it'd be nicer if you could also include the first few lines of the stack-trace : it discloses a lot of context, in particular the line where it was raised.

Answer (score 2):

You have misunderstood the usage of `Scanner` methods : `sc.nextLine();` consumes and returns the line.
That means that you're currently reading the whole file with `sc.nextLine();`, discarding the result, and only then you try to read 4 ints, that can't be read since the Scanner is at the end of the file.

You should instead use one of these two methods :

- If you're positive that each line of your file contains 4 ints separated by space (or any other specific character), and nothing more, you can then scan 4 ints while the scanner has a next line.
- If there might be variations, or useless data, you should keep your `hasNextLine()` and `nextLine()` calls as they are, then use regex, split+indexing or another Scanner to retrieve the 4 ints from the line.